# Does dotliquid support 'not' as an operator?

Tags: c#, dotliquid

dotliquid support Basic operators like and/or.

```
Basic operators

Operator    Function
==  equals
!=  does not equal
>   greater than
<   less than
>=  greater than or equal to
<=  less than or equal to
or  condition A or condition B
and condition A and condition B
```

Does support 'not' as operator ?

Comment: It seems not to, according to this open github issue https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/issues/138

Answer (score 2):

It contains `unless` as control flow, seen here:

https://shopify.github.io/liquid/tags/control-flow/

Which means:

```
if a && b && !c
  # ...
end
```

Translates into:

```
{% if a and b %}
  {% unless c %}
    ...
  {% endunless %}
{% endif %}
```